# Add color symbol to axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a boxplot with same color boxes. I would like to name the axis with labs(), and add a small symbol in the color of the plot's boxes.

```
sector <- c("HY", "HY (ETFs)", "IG", "IG (ETFs)", "Loan", "Equities")
YTD_percent <- c(-0.2, 0.5, 0.05, 0.2, -0.1, 0.1)
data1 <- data.frame(sector, YTD_percent)

ggplot(data1, aes(sector, YTD_percent)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="#00669C", fill="#00669C", width=0.7) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, title = "Plot Title") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
        )+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 1, keyheight = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(), expand = c(.05, .05), labels=percent) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sector , y = YTD_percent), hjust = ifelse(data_ff$YTD_percent >= 0, -0.1, 1.1), size=6)
```

[image]

This is what the axis should look like in the end:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could include fill in your aesthetics mapping and tune the legend a little bit:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(data1, aes(sector, YTD_percent, fill = "YTD (in %)")) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="#00669C",  width=0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("YTD (in %)" = "#00669C")) + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, title = "Plot Title", fill = "") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom"
  )+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 1, keyheight = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(), expand = c(.05, .05), labels=percent) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sector , y = YTD_percent), hjust = ifelse(data1$YTD_percent >= 0, -0.1, 1.1), size=6)
```

[image]